# Is the Tigris in Mockingjay the same Tigris as the one in Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes?

Tags: the-hunger-games, mockingjay, ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Those who have read *Mockingjay* and *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* know that someone named Tigris appears in both of the stories. What I don't know is if she is the same person in both stories, or if it is a coincidence and both share the same name. Can this be clarified, please?

Comment: There is a discussion of this on literature.SE: https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18449/are-tigris-in-the-hunger-games-and-tigris-in-the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've answered a nearly-identical question on our sister site; [Literature: SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18449/are-tigris-in-the-hunger-games-and-tigris-in-the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes)

> ### Their professions.
>
> *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*
> Not much of a  student,  Tigris had forgone university when she’d graduated from the Academy to pursue her dream of becoming a designer. - **Coriolanus Snow**
>
> *Mockingjay*
> She was a fixture—a younger, less disturbing version of herself—in the earliest Hunger Games I can remember. A stylist, I think. I don’t remember for which district. Not 12. Then she must have had one operation too many and crossed the line into repellence. - **Katniss Everdeen**
>
> Both Tigrises have the same profession. While the Tigris in *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* wants to become a designer, the one in *Mockingjay* is. It is very possible that they are the same person, the Tigris in *Mockingjay* having fulfilled her dream. Based on this, it could be possible that they are the same person.
>
> ### Habits of Eating Meat
>
> *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*
> Tigris craved it and would have eaten her whole portion raw if the Grandma’am hadn’t forbidden it. - **Coriolanus Snow**
>
> *Mockingjay*
> “I eat next to nothing,” she says. “And then, only raw meat." - **Tigris Snow**
>
> In both stories, Tigris enjoys eating raw meat, something that two people with the name Tigris may not share. It is even more unlikely for someone named Tigris to want to go into fashion and eat raw meat.
>
> ### Their eye color.
>
> *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*
> He noticed the lilac circles under [Tigris's] golden brown eyes and couldn’t help feeling a pang of guilt. “When was the last time you slept?” he asked - **Coriolanus Snow**
>
> *Mockingjay*
> I have a moment of panic and find myself turning to Tigris, searching those tawny eyes. - **Katniss Everdeen**
>
> Tawny is a color similar to a golden brown, but a bit more orange. I've added images of the two colors below. The one on the left is golden-brown and the one on the right is tawny. Although the colors are different, there have been studies in which eye color changes with age. It is very possible that Tigris's eyes darkened slightly as she aged, or she changed the color to look more like her namesake. It is mentioned above in the first *Mockingjay* quote that Tigris has had operations.
>
> [image: Golden-Brown]
> [image: Tawny]

Based on these three points, I concluded that the Tigris in *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* and *Mockingjay* were the same person.